# Adding an embedded HTML5 YouTube video to my "likes"

Tags: youtube, embed, html5, favorites, youtube-watch-later

I am slightly annoyed that the only way that I can bookmark an embedded HTML5 YouTube video is by pressing the "watch later" clock () on top right.

I believe this has changed with the HTML5 player, as I used to be able to vote up () videos with the Flash player.

It seems strange to me that this feature was removed, since the "watch later" feature is very similar in the way it functions, as it writes data on the user's "watch later" list.

I went to my YouTube settings, as well as looked online for an answer on whether or not this can be toggled, but didn't find anything.

Example of embedded HTML5 video without the  action but with the :

[image]

So, is there a way to add a video to one's favorites or  from the embedded HTML5 player?

Answer (score 2):

YouTube is changing the player from time to time, and they indeed removed the ability to like a video both in embeds and in full screen. There is no toggle or option or anything to bring it back, at least not via YouTube-native features.

I don't know the reasoning behind it, though if I had to guess it's because nobody used this feature, unlike the watch later feature.

If you do want it back, it's best to send feedback (at the bottom of any YouTube page or at the bottom of the sidebar of any YouTube page) and explain why you want it back.